# Backpack for Laravel Vendor Files are not updating when I walk through Upgrade Guide (4.0 - 4.1)

Tags: laravel-backpack

I'm attempting to update Backpack for Laravel from 4.0 to 4.1

I've noticed that when looking at my views/vendor/backpack folder none of the default elements have been updated at all. (i.e. crud/buttons, crud/columns) beyond the manual updates that I've made per the upgrade instructions.

To be more specific I'm referring to all the files located here. 
https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/tree/4.1/src/resources/views/base

There are tons of updates in these files that have not been copied over to my project. Did I miss a step in the upgrade guide?

Comment: As of right now I had to go through every single one of these files and check for changes and then manually update them. Seems like there has to be a better way to override these default templates.

Comment: Indeed James - the upgrade is 100% manual, Backpack won't make any changes to the files in your `views/vendor/backpack` folder, because it has no idea what it'll find there :-) That's userland, it can be completely custom. You shouldn't have too many files there, only the ones you (or the developer before you) published to modify - usually it's very few files. If you do have A LOT of files, it's probably because the developer before you chose to publish ALL files, even if they didn't modify all of them. Which is bad practice, because published files don't get updates.

Comment: If you're in this situation (A LOT of published views) I'm afraid the only way to get out of it is manual. Either compare them with the files in 4.0 (diff should return very few or no differences), and delete the ones which were mistakenly published. OR compare them with the files in 4.1 directly, and for each file decide if it's worth keeping the file in `resources/views/base` or you can just delete it, and Backpack will then use the one in the package. I'm afraid this are the only solutions I see.